# Dense projections of lattices in $G\times\textrm{Aut}(T)$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $G$ be a simple connected Lie group and let $T$ be a $k$-regular tree. Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $G\times\textrm{Aut}(T)$.

<s>Assume that the intersection of $\Gamma$ with each direct factor is infinite.</s>

If the projection of $\Gamma$ to $G$ is dense, can we say anything about the projection to $\textrm{Aut}(T)$?

Comment: What do you have in mind? Some examples are quite intensively studied, for instance the Baumslag-Solitar groups $\text{BS}(1,n) = \langle x,t \mid t x t^{-1}=x^n\rangle$ where $G = \text{PSL}_2 \mathbb R$ and $T$ is the $n+1$-regular tree.

Comment: Do you have any references for where the Baumslag-Solitar groups are treated as lattices? But I am particularly interested in the most general case, so any $\Gamma$ as above.

Comment: My own papers with Farb study $\text{BS}(1,n)$ and certain other solvable groups $\Gamma$ by studying the two actions arising from the embedding in $G \times \text{Aut}(T)$: the action on the symmetric space of $G$; and the action on the tree $T$. We knew of no general theory at the time, and I don't know of any general theory that has arisen, although it's possible there might be one waiting to be discovered.

Comment: @LeeMosher This discrete embedding of $BS(1,n)$ has infinite covolume, but is cocompact in an explicit subgroup of the product (a suitable fibre product over an abelian quotient of the closure of projections). See https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6765

Comment: The assumption that intersection $H=G\cap\Gamma$ with $G$ is infinite and the projection is dense implies that $H$ is normal in $G$, and hence $H=G$. So these assumptions are just absurd. Maybe you wanted to assume that these intersections are finite?

Comment: @YCor: Yes, I think of it as a certain fiber product of $\mathbb H^2$ and $T$ over the real line, in the setting that Farb and I worked in, similar to how 3-d solv geometry is a fiber product of two $\mathbb H^2$'s over the real line.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes (that's the space rather than the group).

Comment: @YCor Yes I think you're right.  What happens if you assume finite?

Comment: At least, if $p=k-1$ is prime, the closure can be $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ or a finite index subgroup therein. We obtain some more examples using groups of $\mathbf{Q}_p$-rank 1 (and higher absolute rank); I'm not sure whether the tree has valency $p+1$ then. I don't know if there are other examples.